# AdMob Banner ad not showing when running app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob

I think that I setup the code for the Banner Ad correctly but the is is not showing up when I run the application in the simulator or on my iPhone.

```
@IBOutlet var BannerAD: GADBannerView!

@IBOutlet var ScoreLabel: UILabel!

var taps = Int(){
    didSet {
        if taps == 330 {
            print("You have reaches 5 taps !!")
        }
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //BannerView
    let request = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
    BannerAD.delegate = self
    BannerAD.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-1469592343938512/3073825187"
    BannerAD.rootViewController = self
    BannerAD.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: Did you set it up properly in the storyboard so it appears properly (using constraints)?

Comment: Yes i set it up properly.

Comment: Are you sure the size of it is big enough. Sometimes if the size is too small for the ad it doesn't appear

Comment: the size of the uiview is 320x 50 for AdMob Banner Ads and mine is exactly scaled like this.

Comment: Are there any errors printed out in the box bellow in xcode?

Comment: no there is nothing it is just not showing the ad

Comment: When I paste in the second line of code Xcode shows me an error (arguments width, height, x, y do not match any available overloads)

Comment: I bet this is an issue with your auto layout code. You should also integrate the `GADBannerViewDelegate` methods so you can know when you receive an ad or it receives an error from AdMob's servers

Comment: Check this example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39429302/2108547. This is not using auto layout though.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `viewDidLoad` (but before you make the ad request):

```
BannerAd = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
```

When you do this, you **might** need to set the frame of your ad like so:

```
BannerAd.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50)
```

Comment: When I paste in the second line of code Xcode shows me an error (arguments width, height, x, y do not match any available overloads)

Comment: Does it work without the second line? I modified the second line too

Comment: No it is unfortunately not working. There is no error anymore but it does not work nevertheless.

Comment: @JuliIchSelber What was the original error? You didn't say anything about an error. Also, define: "It's not working"

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement GADBannerViewDelegate delegate methods to check if app is receiving ads:

```
func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!) {
   print("ad received")
}

func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
   print("fail to receive ad with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```